# Software tool to easily create simplified Gantt diagrams

Tags: linux, web-apps, diagram

I need to create simplified Gantt charts similar to the attached one (extracted from *Fundamentos básicos de los sistemas operativos* (2011)):

[image: Simplified Gantt Chart]

The idea is to represent which process was using the CPU and I/O channels as time went by.

Preferrably a Linux program or an online tool, although I could do with a Windows one as well. No need to do anything much more complicated than what show in the picture, so the simpler the tool, the better.